# Xcode - customize navigation bar height

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

Is there anyway, to costumize the default navigation bar tittle position, height, and buttons position?

Tks!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to properly implement a custom navigation bar.

Comment: ANd is it possible to give him the same behavior from a default nabigationbar? Like when i tap back, I've the last view saved on memory and that kind of stuff?

Comment: You subclass the navigation bar. It has all the functionality of its superclass unless you overwrite it.